# C#, Session object is updated after change in List object

Tags: c#

Can anyone help me out from this ?

```
List<Student> lstStud = new List<Student>();
lstStud = Session["Stud"];
```

When any manipulation in list object `lstStud`. It will automatically update Session also.

So, how to prevent update `Session["Stud"]` ?

Can any one provide some demo about this ?

Comment: It may be duplicate but I din't find exact solution from that.